# Falla a la hora de implementar la protección de las rutas ? [REACT]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

estoy tratando de implementar la proteccion de mis rutas pero está , me falla a la hora de la redirección:

¿Quisiera saber que es lo que está fallando ya que no me redirigé a ninguna ruta, tampoco me marca donde ocurre el error?
Tengo dudas acerca del funcionamiento del render en el Route.

```
function AppRoutes():JSX.Element{
    return (
   <Router>
        <Switch>
       
        <Route  path="/personal" render={(...props)=> <OnlyLogOut {...props} Component={OnlylogOutRoutes} /> } />
        <Route  path="/dashboard"  render={(...props)=> <PrivatesRoutes {...props} Component={RoutesPrivates}/> } />
        </Switch>
             

   </Router>
    )
}
```

Componente OnlyLogout:

```
export function OnlyLogOut({ Component} :{Component:any}, {...rest}) {
    let [role, setrole]:any = useState('');
    console.log('role es :', role);
    useEffect(() => {
       setrole(getRoleUser())
       }, []);
    return (
      <Route 
        {...rest}
          render={props =>
            role === false ? (
              <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/",
                  state: { from: props.location }
                }}
              />
            )
          }
      />
    )
        }
```

Rutas para Onlylogout:

```
function OnlylogOutRoutes():JSX.Element{
    return (
        <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/personal_login" component={LoginScreen}/>
         <Route exact path="/personal_register" component={RegisterScreen}/>
        </Switch>   
    )
}
```

Private Routes:

```
export const PrivatesRoutes = ({Component}:{Component:any}, {...rest}): JSX.Element => {
    let [role, setrole]:any = useState('');
    console.log('role es :' ,role);
    useEffect(() => {
       setrole(getRoleUser())
       }, []);

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
          render={props =>
            role === "admin" ? (
              <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/login",
                  state: { from: props.location }
                }}
              />
            )
          }
      />
    )
        }
```

```
export const PrivatesRoutes = ({Component}:{Component:any}, {...rest}): JSX.Element => {
    let [role, setrole]:any = useState('');
    console.log('role es :' ,role);
    useEffect(() => {
       setrole(getRoleUser())
       }, []);

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
          render={props =>
            role === "admin" ? (
              <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/login",
    
                }}
              />
            )
          }
      />
    )
        }
```

Tambien tenia otra duda:
¿Es necesario colocar el render en el componente route y que funcion cumple el render?
Porque vi algunos ejemplos donde podria colocar directamente de esta forma:

```
     <Switch>
          <PublicRoutes path="/auth" component={ AuthRouter } isAuthenticated={islogged/>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo buen día te voy a mostrar un ejemplo de como debes redireccionar las rutas:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";

// Importing the Context Provider & Home Component
import Home from './components/Home';

import Ubicacion from './components/pagina/Ubicacion';


function App(props) {
  return (
   <MyContextProvider>
      <Router>
      <Home/>

       <Switch>
           <Route path={'/Ubicacion'} component = {Ubicacion}></Route>
          
           <Route component={Ubicacion}/>
         </Switch>


      </Router>
    </MyContextProvider>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```